# "The connection was reset" ERROR: after changing avatar photo in edit profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, devise, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just deployed my site on AWS Elasticbeanstalk.  Im using postgres, puma, paperclip.  For some odd reason when I try to edit my profile "using devise" and change the photo to another photo and click submit I get an error: "The connection was reset" I really have no clue to why this is!! How can I change a photo??? Thank you!!

I have this log however that shows only what happens when trying to view the photo that i selected in the first place. From what my nginx/error.log shows is that the file size "picture" that i try to add is too large.. so how can I fix this?? I followed a response to this by adding folder called .ebextensions with a file called 01_files.config

**01_files.config**

```yaml
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        http {
          client_max_body_size 20M;
        }
```

### /var/log/nginx/error.log

2016/06/04 03:34:01 [warn] 15075#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2016/06/04 03:56:42 [error] 2805#0: *23810 client intended to send too large body: 2771639 bytes, client: 172.31.36.95, server: _, request: "POST / HTTP/1.1", host:

**Error Log:**
I, [2016-06-04T03:15:39.389493 #14337]  INFO -- : Started GET "/system/users/avatars/000/000/008/thumb/IMG_0645.JPG?1465010122" for 221.146.103.246 at 2016-06-04 03:15:39 +0000
F, [2016-06-04T03:15:39.391271 #14337] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/system/users/avatars/000/000/008/thumb/IMG_0645.JPG"):

Comment: Please do two things: give permission to public/system folder and second try with small size file.

Comment: yes i figured out that it has to do with having too big of a file size and i looked up an answer like creating a folder called `.ebextensions` and adding a file called `01_files.config` ill updat my post on the bottom to show what i added to the 01_files.config... but it still didnt work or do anything

Comment: Also where do i find public/system folder? I dont have one in my app i dont think

Comment: in your mail folder go to public

Comment: Are you talking about app/mailer? I dont have a public file or folder located in this app/mailer folder.  Should I make one there? And what should I put in it? Im new to beanstalk, not really sure how to do some things. :*(

Comment: out of app, please go to root folder then find folder public

Comment: public folder is not in app, it is with app

Comment: oooo okay I know now!! yea i have! and are you taking about setting permissions through my comptuer in console or through the aws website? like chmod 775?